# How does python @ for decorators handles recursive functions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build (and fully understand) a memoization decorator for a recursive Fibonacci function.

```py
# variable-stored decorator version

def memoize(function):
    stored_returns = {}
    
    def memo_helper(args):
        if args in stored_returns:
            return stored_returns[args]
        
        instance_return = function(args)
        stored_returns[args] = instance_return
        
        return instance_return
    
    return memo_helper

def fibo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibo(n-2) + fibo(n-1)

memoized_fibo = memoize(fibo)

print(memoized_fibo(30))
```

The program prints the expected `memoized_fibo(30)`, 832040.

However, it's not memoizing `fibo` at all. In fact, `memoized_fibo()` calls the first `fibo()` as expected, but that first `fibo` recursively calls regular `fibo`s, not memoized ones, which does not reduce the complexity of the function at all. The program takes a couple of seconds to calculate `memoized_fibo(30)`.

However, when decorating `fibo` via python's `@` operator, somehow the recursion works as expected, allowing a linear function, which calculates `fibo(30)` in a couple of milliseconds:

```py
# @ decorator version
def memoize(function):
    stored_returns = {}
    
    def memo_helper(args):
        if args in stored_returns:
            return stored_returns[args]
        
        instance_return = function(args)
        stored_returns[args] = instance_return
        
        return instance_return
    
    return memo_helper

@memoize
def fibo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibo(n-2) + fibo(n-1)

print(fibo(30))
```

I would like to know how `@` handles that recursive situation under the hood, so I can implement my own variable-stored decorators.

Comment: Your first method explicitly creates an undecorated function `fibo()` and that’s what gets called recursively. The second method only creates a decorated `fibo()` method - the code below `def fibo` is embedded in the `memo_helper()` function) so that’s what gets called.

Comment: I was suspecting that, but I didn't manage to call memoize inside memoize. Do you have any resources i could read about how doing it?

Comment: It’s the local definition of `memo_helper()` (there’s one definition for each function decorated by `memoize()`)  that gets called (but not by name, the reference is returned by `memoize()`) when your code calls the decorated `fibo`.

Answer (score 1):

@memoize is a syntatic sugar for fibo = memoize(fibo)

the function parameter in your memoize func now references the original fibo. @memoize simply use the name fibo to reference the helper function that makes use of the original fibo function.

Try read up about decorators.
[realpython](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators)  has a good article on it